# Change drop down list values when another user makes a choice from another drop down list in the same form

Tags: php, javascript

My question is: How can i change the options-values from one list according to what a user choose from another drop down list. My issue here is that these both lists must be populated with a query.

```
<label for="category"></label>
          <select name="category" id="category">
          <option value="0" >Choose Category</option>


<?php foreach(Categories::find_all() as $id) :?>
        <?php echo "<option value=".$id->id .">". $id->cat_name."</option>"; ?>
        <?php endforeach?>
```

```
<label for="sub_category"></label>
          <select name="sub_category" id="sub_category">
          <option value="0" >Choose Sub Category</option>



<?php foreach(Categories_sub::find_by_cat_id(????) as $id) :?>
    <?php echo "<option value=".$id->id .">". $id->cat_sub_name."</option>"; ?>
    <?php endforeach?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in one of the following ways, both involve javascript:

1.
When the first select box value changes, load the second select box with AJAX (remove the current second select box).

2.
Print out all select boxes. Then show and hide the right select box with javascript. This does not involve AJAX, but you need to check the first select box with PHP to check which second select box should be handled.

I would advise a framework like jQuery to do one of these 2 options.